# Symfony 2, entity without file?

Tags: php, symfony

**Situation:**

I have a MySQL database with hundreds of tables that will be generated by admin action.
I want to use the benefits of symfony entities, but i don't want to generate hundreds of entity files for that.

**Goal:**

Have something like an entity factory that returns me the objects for a table.

**Zend Framework:**

```
$bugTable = new Zend_Db_Table('job_153');
```

Are there ways to realize that with symfony 2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to define entities dynamically at runtime.

If you have a complex schema maybe the `doctrine:mapping:import` could be useful to generate automatically the mapping files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i don't want hundreds or even thousands of entity files in my Entity directory.

Comment: Try it before saying that. Doctrine will generate a class for each table. If you have hundred of tables, I think you have a big database design problem.

Comment: Take a look at content management systems based on mysql, there is no way around generating tables ...without loss of runtime performance

Answer (score 0):

After some research, i think it's not possible with build in methods.